# Multiple errors when trying to install tensorflow gpu beta 2.0 in virtual env on a windows machine using pip

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to install tensorflow 2.0 beta on my windows machine using pip. I am using the requirements.txt from 
https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2/blob/master/requirements.txt

The only change I have made is to use the beta tensorflow version instead of the tf-nightly-preview version.

`#tf-nightly-2.0-preview`
`#tf-nightly-gpu-2.0-preview`
`tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0-beta1`

I am getting three errors -

```
ERROR: tensorflow-gpu 2.0.0b1 has requirement tb-nightly<1.14.0a20190604,>=1.14.0a20190603, but you'll have tb-nightly 1.15.0a20190617 which is incompatible.

ERROR: tfp-nightly 0.8.0.dev20190617 has requirement cloudpickle==1.1.1, but you'll have cloudpickle 1.2.1 which is incompatible.
```

and the last one

```
    ERROR: Complete output from command 'D:\Data\Study\4hml\handson-ml2\env\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Vidya\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hsmwtwf3\\cityhash\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Vidya\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-05j38rg_\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'D:\Data\Study\4hml\handson-ml2\env\include\site\python3.7\cityhash':
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'cityhash' extension
    creating build
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src
    D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Iinclude -ID:\Data\Study\4hml\handson-ml2\env\include "-ID:\Program Files\Python37\include" "-ID:\Program Files\Python37\include" "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\ATLMFC\include" "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\include" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-ID:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpsrc/city.cc /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src/city.obj -O3 -Wno-unused-value -Wno-unused-function
    cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wno-unused-value'
    error: command 'D:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.21.27702\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'D:\Data\Study\4hml\handson-ml2\env\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Vidya\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hsmwtwf3\\cityhash\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Vidya\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-05j38rg_\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'D:\Data\Study\4hml\handson-ml2\env\include\site\python3.7\cityhash'" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Vidya\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hsmwtwf3\cityhash\
```

I have the following installed

- Python 3.7.3
- Visual Studio Community Edition 2019
- CUDA Toolkit / cuDNN sdk / CUPTI
  ( I ran the CUDA installation sample solutions - deviceQuery and bandwidthTest and they worked without issues )
- Tensor RT 5.0
  ( The sampleMNIST solution also worked with no problems )

I upgraded 
**pip** (Version 19.1.1)

**setuptools** (Version 41.0.1)

**virtualenv** (Version 16.6.1)

After that created a virtual environment, activated it and then ran

`python -m pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt`

Do I need to downgrade my python version ? Does tensorflow 2.0 Beta not work with python 3.7.3 ?

And for the cl error from windows

`cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wno-unused-value`

All indications are that that is a gcc flag but I don't know how to remove it and where to remove it from the setup.

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/sigs/testing/faq.md is showing that "Support for Python 3.5 and 3.7 will be added for TensorFlow 2.0."

Comment: Tried with python 3.6 - I get the same 3 errors ! With both the beta version of tensorflow and the nightly-gpu-preview version of tensorflow.

Comment: It looks like you have version incompatibilities to resolve.  I've got TF 2.0 beta running on python 3.7, but not concurrently with TF 1.  Do you have TF 1 already running where you're trying to install TF 2.0?

Comment: I don't already have TF1. For the cityhash problem I created an issue in github and it looks like they may use a substitute library(s). The link for that is github.com/tensorflow/datasets/issues/690. However the other two errors remain. Do you have windows machine ? I tried this setup in google colab too - the same two errors for cloudpickle and tbnightly exist.

Comment: For the cityhash problem  - the resolution was to swap siphash in the library itself.  (Github link - https://github.com/tensorflow/datasets/issues/690)                                
I noticed however at the time of writing this - that it had not yet been removed from required packages.  For the tb-nightly issue - can install tb_nightly==1.14.0a20190614 instead of just tb-nightly.  The cloud pickle problem is due to conflicting  2 packages (scikit-image and tfp-nightly) both requiring two different version of cloudpickle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In the newer commits for tfds - the cityhash library has been swapped with siphash.
2. For tensorflow the tb_nightly dependency is expected to be updated mid-July so if installing after that - the issue may not even arise.
3. Since cloudpickle versions for two packages are different need to upgrade one of them or downgrade the other.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Upgrading your setup tools will solve the problem.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools==41.0.0
```

Comment: I had upgraded setuptools first.